# MySQL Delete from 1 table, using multiple tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to delete all the rows found by that query:

```
SELECT cart_abandon.*
FROM cart_abandon, cart_product, txn_product, users
WHERE cart_abandon.cartid = cart_product.cartid
AND cart_product.productid = txn_product.productid
AND txn_product.username = users.username
AND users.id = cart_abandon.userid
AND txn_product.txndate >= cart_abandon.abandondate
```

The thing to keep in mind is that the query here uses 4 different tables, however I only want to delete rows from 1 table (cart_abandon).

Is there an easy way to do that? Maybe this: ?

```
DELETE cart_abandon
FROM cart_abandon, cart_product, txn_product, users
WHERE cart_abandon.cartid = cart_product.cartid
AND cart_product.productid = txn_product.productid
AND txn_product.username = users.username
AND users.id = cart_abandon.userid
AND txn_product.txndate >= cart_abandon.abandondate
```

Is that valid? Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check delete multiple-table on syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html

Comment: But what I understood from it led me to the proposed query I wrote above - is that correct?

Comment: It seems that your query is ok, you use the fist syntax (rows get deleted from the table[s] before FROM  :
DELETE cart_abandon 
FROM

Comment: I'd change it a bit by using INNER JOIN instead of listing all the tables in FROM , but it shouldn't make any difference for the server. It would be easy to read though...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **subqueries**:

Would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM foo
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * from bar WHERE ..)
```

Check this site for further informations:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE cart_abandon
WHERE cartid IN (
   SELECT cart_abandon.cartid
   FROM cart_abandon, cart_product, txn_product, users
   WHERE cart_abandon.cartid = cart_product.cartid
   AND cart_product.productid = txn_product.productid
   AND txn_product.username = users.username
   AND users.id = cart_abandon.userid
   AND txn_product.txndate >= cart_abandon.abandondate
)
```